# Apache Cordova Redirection using InAppBrowser

Tags: javascript, html, apache, cordova

Alright so all what's needed to be done is to open a mobile application get hyperlinked or anchor-tagged into a website url and that's it. I've already customized the CSS on various screen to exactly look like a mobile application.

I created the cordova app on arch, added the plugin then meta-tagged the index.html as:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Unfortunately it took me outside of the application. So i tried redirecting to the internal /js directory and used this according to apache Cordova's main documentation.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Still didn't work, it's very clear that it's just defining a variable here and that's my question.

How could automatic redirection to an external link be done in such a platform so that it never leaves the app?

PS: I've already prepared navigation buttons, login, look and feel, menu logouts and everything, just having this step missing.

Answer (score 0):

I use the inAppBrowser plugin like this:

```
window.open('http://url/', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

If you keep the "http" it will try to open an external web, but if you remove it it will load a file on your internal storage.

What this does is opening a "browser" on top of your app, but if all you want is to load local recurses yo can do it by adding urls without the "http".

Comment: Great, so this line is to be placed in www/index.html or www/js/index.js or meta-tagged from index.html to index.js?

Comment: You can add it on an event, or call it from elsewhere, just as you need it.